# Delete query in SQL (Access) in conjuction with dependent data?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, sql-delete, ms-access-2016

I know this is a very basic question but I am unable to get it done. Just started to learn more about databases. I have two tables: tblFoodAllowance and tblTravelDays.

tblFoodAllowance consists of ID, tripID, dateDay, costs.
tblTravelDay saves all days when I was on a business trip: ID, dateDay.

I am looking for a delete query in SQL to use in MS Access which does this: Delete all from tblFoodAllowance where tripID is xy (e.g. 1) and tblFoodAllowance.dateDay is not in the list of tblTravelDates. How can I achieve this?

I tried multiple things but either I got a syntax error or a wrong result. Thanks for your help.

I guess it is something like:

```
DELETE * FROM tblFoodAllowance WHERE tblFoodAllowance.tripID = [tripID] and ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `delete`:

```
delete from tblFoodAllowance
    where tripID = @xy and
          not exists (select 1
                      from tblTravelDates
                      where tblTravelDates.tripId = tblFoodAllowance.tripId and
                            tblTravelDates.dateDay = tblFoodAllowance.dateDay
                     );
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `not exists` and a correlated subquery. It is a bit unclear exactly which colums connect the two tables, but the idea is:

```
delete from tblFoodAllowance 
where 
    tripID = 1
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from tblTravelDay
        where tblTravelDay.dateDay = tblFoodAllowance.dateDay
    )
```

Comment: This works but surprisingly I had to run it twice to delete all the specified records. Why is that?